# How to pass parameter to function in AngularJS with promises

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I wan to send parameter to service function.

> getQuestions : function(stateCode)   : questionResource.js

stateCode is set in $scope from the response of dtoResource.rc1Step1DTO()

```
angular
    .module('autoQuote')
    //Do initalization on page load
    .run(['$log', '$rootScope', '$state', 'dtoResource', 'questionResource', function($log, $rootScope, $state, dtoResource, questionResource) {
        $log.info('Post DTO on page load.');
        dtoResource.rc1Step1DTO()
            .then(questionResource.getQuestions)
            .then(function(questions) {
                $rootScope.questions = questions;
                console.log('Obtained questions. Assigned to rootscope');
            })
            .then(function() {
                console.log('This should be printed after the above methods are done     executing');
                console.log($rootScope);
            });

    }])
```

How to pass state code to the other function.
its position in scope is

```
$scope.postAutoQuoteObj.SessionInfo.StateCode
```

Below is the plunker for code
http://plnkr.co/edit/Op1QDwUBECAosPUC7r3N?p=preview

Comment: Your `run()` function runs before your controller even exists, and the `$scope` that you're talking about is not accessible from within the `run()` function. I think you need to resolve the logistics of _that_ first.

Comment: functions I wrote  in .run I want to execute after dom loaded, but these methods are independent and  should be in synchronous order. Can you please suggest what changes I should do. before working on parameter pass issue.

Answer (score 0):

your module autoQuote.run() will only be called once during your applications loading. So don't expect to have it execute again.

you are close to the right answer. you just need to do some reorganization. One tip I would offer is to worry about creating a directive later, first get the controllers, routes working first.
You have created an excellent framework to start. you are using ui-router.
this means that you can tell ui-router what controller to execute when a state is requested.  so the life cycle for your application is as follows

module.run //any code in here first. only on intial load
module.config //in your case app.config which creates your states.

then depending what state you are viewing based on the url;
the controller for that state (or view) will be executed

so if you add another state config for / you can bind that state to your autoQuoteCtrl.

additionally, there are a number of other issues, such as attempting to use ng-model and value in an input element. this is not correct.

you are not implementing your ui-views. this will mean your controllers will never execute. technically, it your case autoQuoteCtrl would be executed but only because you forced it onto the page using ng-controller, which is what ui-router is designed to avoid.

which I think is why you ended up placing your code in .run(). This was the only place you found your applicaton would "run" the code on page load which is false, it was only running because your app loaded. Sorry if I'm being redundant. But it is an  important point.

Also, you are trying to access your json data by passing statecode to your resource. that is not how $resource works. you pass the name of the resource, and it will return everything at that resource. then you filter the code after the promise is returned. you only have one resource. that is "CA.json" so therefore you should be able to get away with only one line in your resource service and only need one resource service.  You will need additional non-resource services that can do the heaving lifting of filtering out the correct data from the JSON. typically this is why an app would call out to different resources, so that each one returns the model needed, not a single monolithic resource.

and you should never ever ever be using `document.getElementById()` you are using angular, so you do not interact with the dom directly

finally, here is a much much revised plunkr to help guide you in the right direction.

http://plnkr.co/edit/dUJm01uu7RnhltC2pLLb?p=preview